# pre image and continuity

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : R^n → R
^m$ be a continuous map. The pre-image $f^
{−1}
(U) ⊆ R^
n$
is open if the
subset U ⊆ $R^m$ is open.

Give an example of a function $f:R^m→R^n$ and a subset $⊆ R^
n$ which shows the assumption of continuity is essential.

I can't seem to find an example that shows the essential of continuity

Comment: I'm not sure I even understand the question. Assumption of continuity in *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if $x=0$,}\\
0 & \mbox{ else.}
\end{cases}$ Then $f^{-1}((\frac{1}{2}, 2))=\left\{0\right\}$, which is not open.

Comment: The fact that a set is closed doesn't mean it's not open - eg. empty set. What is needed is that the set $\{0\}$ is not open, which is of course true. :)

Comment: That's very true, topological spaces are not doors.

Comment: Allow me to steal that one! :)

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain why this shows continuity is essential?

Comment: This map is not continuous and we have an open $U=(\frac{1}{2},2)\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open. Also the definition of a continuous map is a map such that the inverse image of every open is open. If you don't know that last sentence, you should give us your definition of open, or better yet, prove for yourself that your condition is equivalent to this one.

Comment: @Andrew: You're allowed to steal that one, it's a great oneliner.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I agree and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity and you know that according to this definition, the 'sign' function,
$$\operatorname{sgn} :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$$
is discontinuous at $0$.

Then the preimage of the open interval $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ is the one point set $\{0\}$ which is not open - in the usual topology.